# Accessing a non existent column of a data.table with dollar sign

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the (probably outdated) version 1.10.4 of data.table with R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31). I can access non-existent columns with the dollar sign. Is this behaviour wanted?

code:

```
realOffloads = data.table(BAG_TAG = c(1,2,3))
realOffloads = realOffloads[, .(BAG_TAG, OFFLOAD_REAL = T)]
"OFFLOAD" %in% names(realOffloads)
x = realOffloads$OFFLOAD
```

although I am getting 'FALSE' as an answer to the question whether or not the column 'OFFLOAD' exists I am getting something out of it (T,T,T) when accessing it using the dollar sign.

I was using that pretty often in the code so now I am a little scared :-()

Regards, 
FW

Comment: This is from base R, for example `list(a = 2)$b`. If you want data.table to throw an error, you can extract the column like `data.table(a = 1)[, b]` instead. Or write `if ("b" %in% names(DT)) x = DT$b else stop("zomg")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the base R documentation:

> Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list. The main difference
>   is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does. `x$name` is
>   equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`. Also, the partial matching
>   behavior of `[[` can be controlled using the exact argument.

A `data.table` is a `data.frame`, and a `data.frame` is a `list`, thus a `data.table` is a `list`. So inexact matching with `$` is allowed. That's nice for an interactive session where you're trying to quickly explore the data, but not so nice for non-interactive code that can blow up when the unexpected happens.

This is why it's *almost always* a bad idea to use `$` for subsetting if you're not 100% sure the column exists. And even then, it could fall prey to typos. Instead of `DT$name`, use `DT[["name"]]`. This won't raise an error, but it will return `NULL`, which is easy to check. Even if you let it go, that `NULL` will probably cause an error down the line.

Comment: The reason I like to use the dollar sign is that it has some auto completion, i.e. when I have a column named LONG_AND_COMPLICATED_COLUMN_NAME then I always have to copy/paste when accessing it with dt[["..."]]... for doing the same with the dollar sign I just have to type dt$LO and then RStudio will automatically complete it for me...

Comment: You're right: the dollar sign is meant and great for interactive use.  But it becomes a risk in non-interactive code.  I'll edit my response to make this distinction.